# How to integrate selenium IDE testcases to azure devops pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, selenium-ide

I have installed the selenium IDE extension for firefox and have recorded and created a testsuite with 5 testcases for testing 5 different functionalities of my application.Now how do i integrate these tests/testsuite to my azure devops pipeline?.I mean what type of task should i add to my pipeline for this purpose? The idea is to run this test automatically when new code is committed to the azure repository.The saved testsuite is using the .side format.I am also able to export my test suite to different languages like  Java+JUnit,JavaScript+Mocha etc.Now how do i proceed from here if i want to integrate these tests to my azure pipeline?plz help?

testcode generated after exporting to javascript moacha

```
// Generated by Selenium IDE
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver')
const assert = require('assert')

describe('Default Suite', function() {
  this.timeout(30000)
  let driver
  let vars
  beforeEach(async function() {
    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build()
    vars = {}
  })
  afterEach(async function() {
    await driver.quit();
  })
  it('create new folder', async function() {
    await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/")
    await driver.manage().window().setRect(1382, 744)
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".butt > span")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css("input:nth-child(2)")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css("input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("haleem")
    await driver.findElement(By.css("input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys(Key.ENTER)
  })
  it('view creation', async function() {
    await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/")
    await driver.manage().window().setRect(1382, 744)
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 img")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css("h6")).click()
    {
      const dragged = await driver.findElement(By.css(".dragObject:nth-child(8)"))
      const dropped = await driver.findElement(By.css(".col-lg-12:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)"))
      await driver.actions({ bridge: true }).dragAndDrop(dragged, dropped).perform()
    }
    {
      const dragged = await driver.findElement(By.css(".dragObject:nth-child(9)"))
      const dropped = await driver.findElement(By.css(".dropObject"))
      await driver.actions({ bridge: true }).dragAndDrop(dragged, dropped).perform()
    }
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".btn:nth-child(3)")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".saveFormInput")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".saveFormInput")).sendKeys("view sample updated")
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".saveFormButton:nth-child(2)")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 img")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 > li img")).click()
  })
  it('search filter', async function() {
    await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/")
    await driver.manage().window().setRect(550, 692)
    await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("vig")
  })
  it('download functionality', async function() {
    await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/")
    await driver.manage().window().setRect(1382, 744)
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 img")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css("#f3b0fb9b-aa2f-4c14-aa79-f85af92f0fa3 img")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".btn:nth-child(2)")).click()
    await driver.findElement(By.css(".dropObject")).click()
  })
})
```

testcode generated after exporting to Java Junit

```
// Generated by Selenium IDE
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
public class DefaultSuiteTest {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }
  @Test
  public void createnewfolder() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1382, 744));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".butt > span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input:nth-child(2)")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("haleem");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  }
  @Test
  public void viewcreation() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1382, 744));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h6")).click();
    {
      WebElement dragged = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dragObject:nth-child(8)"));
      WebElement dropped = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col-lg-12:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.dragAndDrop(dragged, dropped).perform();
    }
    {
      WebElement dragged = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dragObject:nth-child(9)"));
      WebElement dropped = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dropObject"));
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      builder.dragAndDrop(dragged, dropped).perform();
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn:nth-child(3)")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".saveFormInput")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".saveFormInput")).sendKeys("view sample updated");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".saveFormButton:nth-child(2)")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 > li img")).click();
  }
  @Test
  public void searchfilter() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(550, 692));
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("vig");
  }
  @Test
  public void downloadfunctionality() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1382, 744));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#f1df1abf-ce3d-4fb9-b624-8768957d21b0 img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#f3b0fb9b-aa2f-4c14-aa79-f85af92f0fa3 img")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn:nth-child(2)")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".dropObject")).click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to integrate selenium IDE testcases to azure devops pipeline?

There is a task [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops), which supports:

> unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, and more)
>   using the Visual Studio Test Runner. Other than MSTest-based tests,
>   test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter, such as xUnit,
>   NUnit, **Chutzpah**, can also be executed.

[image]

So, we could use this task to execute the test case for javascript moacha.

But, the exported file is a single file not the library, so we need to create small library project application. We will use this project to compile our test files exported from the Selenium IDE. After we have the project created, we simply need to copy our exported .cs file to our project and compile dll.

If we want to integrate Selenium tests with the Azure devops, we need push this library project to the repos, then use the Visual Studio Test task to build it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my application which iam trying to test  is already pushed to the azure repos

Comment: so are you trying to say that i just have to add a npm task in the build pipeline to run the command npm test?

Comment: my package.json is /* package.json */

{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  }
}

Comment: i have placed the testcase in a folder called test in the root of the azure repository

Comment: iam a little confused plz help.And what is this 'compile dll' that you were refering to?

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan, Is the test case you are talking about a project or a file？

Comment: its a single javascript file(SPEC type) which i got when i exported the recorded testsuite in the selenium IDE tool

Comment: i selected the export as " javascript+mocha " option in the IDE tool for this.I am not sure how to proceed futher. can i directly copy this file to the repository?

Comment: i have also posted the contents of that file in the question itself

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan, That he reason why I told you to create small library project to compile our test files, so we could get the dll file, then we use the that task to test that dll file: similar thread here: https://pxm-software.com/integrating-automated-selenium-tests-with-teamcity/

Comment: ok thank you!!.Do you have any links on  how to create this library project to compile the spec file into a dll file.

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan, Just create the corresponding class library and copy the contents of the generated file to the class library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/unit-testing-javascript-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: hi, after creating a library project(c#) in my local system and added my .cs file to the project , i compiled the project and it generated a .dll file in the /bin folder.So now should i directly upload this dll file to the azure repos and run the visual studio test task to run that dll in my release pipeline ?

Comment: or is there anything else i should do before that?

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan, No, you should upload the library project instead of dll file.

Comment: ok after pushing the library project , which task will actually generate the dll file then?

Comment: "visual studio test" task will pick up the tests only in dll format right?

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan, no, check it by yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops